# maximum trigger depth exceeded Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006R0000009RdT1]

Tags: apex, trigger, recursion

The Trigger below i'm getting error when my IF statement has more that 2 conditions, I Understand it is a recursion issue. However not sure how to fix this, so i can include all the conditions below and more.

```
trigger OppToUpdate on Opportunity (after update) {
    //Create an Empty Opportunity List
    List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
    //Create an Empty Opportunity List for the Update Opportunity that Pertain to the specific Account
    List<Opportunity> oppToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    //Create a set collector for Account's associated to the opportunity
    Set<Id> associatedAccId = new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        associatedAccId.add(opp.AccountId);
    }

    opps=[SELECT Id, AccountId, RFP_Response_Status__c, StageName 
          From Opportunity  
          WHERE AccountId in : associatedAccId];

    for(Opportunity opp : opps){
        if(opp.RFP_Response_Status__c != 'Out of Business'
           || opp.RFP_Response_Status__c != 'Do NOT Call'
           || opp.RFP_Response_Status__c != 'sub-contractor'
           || opp.RFP_Response_Status__c != 'Bad Number'
           && (opp.StageName !='Closed Won' || opp.StageName !='Closed Lost')){
            opp.RFP_Response_Status__c = 'Out of Business';
            opp.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
            oppToUpdate.add(opp);
        }
    }
    if(!oppToUpdate.isEmpty()){
          Update oppToUpdate;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your if statement is incorrect: using OR means that this branch will *always* execute. For example, if RFP Response Status is "Out of business", then it will not be "Bad Number". You need to use && (and) instead of || (or).

```
   if(opp.RFP_Response_Status__c != 'Out of Business'
       && opp.RFP_Response_Status__c != 'Do NOT Call'
       && opp.RFP_Response_Status__c != 'sub-contractor'
       && opp.RFP_Response_Status__c != 'Bad Number'
       && opp.StageName !='Closed Won'
       && opp.StageName !='Closed Lost') {
```

Also, you can build all of this in to your query:

```
Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :associatedAccId AND
                      RFP_Response_Status__c NOT IN ('Out of Business','Do NOT CALL',
                      'sub-contractor','Bad Number') AND
                      StageName NOT IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost')];
```

Also, you should probably specifically *exclude* opportunities that are already in the trigger (or process them independently).

```
Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :associatedAccId AND
                      RFP_Response_Status__c NOT IN ('Out of Business','Do NOT CALL',
                      'sub-contractor','Bad Number') AND
                      StageName NOT IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost')
                      AND Id NOT IN :Trigger.new];
```

So, putting this all together gives you:

```
trigger OppToUpdate on Opportunity (after update) {
    //Create a set collector for Account's associated to the opportunity
    Set<Id> associatedAccId = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        associatedAccId.add(opp.AccountId);
    }

    Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :associatedAccId AND
                          RFP_Response_Status__c NOT IN ('Out of Business','Do NOT CALL',
                          'sub-contractor','Bad Number') AND
                          StageName NOT IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost')
                          AND Id NOT IN :Trigger.new];

    for(Opportunity opp : opps){
        opp.RFP_Response_Status__c = 'Out of Business';
        opp.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
    }
    update opps;
}
```

Comment: Excellent !! it works.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to Make the opp.RFP_Response_Status__c = the value the user choose from the picklist rather than assigning a default one? Also the value user pick from the pick list get passed to the rest of the opportunities related to the same Account ID.

Comment: @Templar Something like `Map<Id, String> rfpResStatus = new Map<Id, String>(); for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) { rfpResStatus.put(opp.AccountId, opp.RFP_Response_Status__c); } ... for(Opportunity opp: opps) { opp.RFP_Response_Status__c = rfpResStatus.get(opp.AccountId); opp.StageName = 'Closed Lost'; } update opps;` You'll also want to add AccountId to the opps query so you can look up the correct account.

Comment: it is working when you have one Opp, However when 2 or more OPP the moment I change the RFP_Response_Status__c to any other different Status other than the above 4 ('Out of Business', 'Do NOT CALL','sub-contractor','Bad Contact Number'), it is marking all the related OPPs to that account as Closed-Lost. It should only mark opp(s) closed-Lost with the status is one of the 4 picklist values AND stage <> close Lost || Close Won.

Comment: @Templar If I understand your comment correctly, it sounds like you need to adjust your first loop: `for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) { if(opp.RFP_Response_Status__c == 'out of business' || opp.RFP_Response_Status__c == 'do not call' ...) { associatedAccId.add(opp.AccountId); } }`

Comment: This Trigger should go off, only after update the RFP_Response_Statuse__C to ("don't call', 'Sub-Contractor', 'Out of Bus', 'Bad Contact NUm') and sets the stage to close-Lost. I'm sorry for the back and forth.

Comment: @Templar Try my code from the prior comment (finish up the OR statements), see if it works for you.

Comment: Yes it is working. The multiple OR statements in the first loop did the trick. thanks

Comment: i've added a test class, and i'm not getting any errors. Not sure if it's doing what it suppose to do?
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124104/test-class-for-my-opportunity-trigger