# Test class for my Opportunity trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I'm writing an apex test class for a trigger and it's showing zero errors, but not sure if the class is passing or not. any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Trigger:

```
trigger OppToUpdate on Opportunity (after update) {
    Map<Id,String> rfpResStatus = new Map<Id,String>();
    //Create a set collector for Account's associated to the opportunity
    Set<Id> associatedAccId = new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new)
    {
        if(opp.RFP_Response_Status__c =='out of business' 
           || opp.RFP_Response_Status__c =='Do Not Call'
           || opp.RFP_Response_Status__c == 'Bad Contact Number'
           || opp.RFP_Response_Status__c == 'sub-contractor')
        {
            associatedAccId.add(opp.AccountId);
            rfpResStatus.put(opp.AccountId,opp.RFP_Response_Status__c); 
        }

    }
    Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Id, AccountId 
                          FROM Opportunity 
                          WHERE AccountId IN :associatedAccId 
                          AND
                          RFP_Response_Status__c NOT IN ('Out of Business',
                          'Do NOT CALL','sub-contractor','Bad Contact Number') 
                          AND
                          StageName NOT IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost')
                          AND Id NOT IN :Trigger.new];

    for(Opportunity opp: opps) 
    { 
        opp.RFP_Response_Status__c = rfpResStatus.get(opp.AccountId); 
        opp.StageName = 'Closed Lost';        
    }
    update opps;
}
```

Test Class for the above trigger is:

```
@isTest
public class Test_OppToUpdate {
    static testMethod void testOppToUpdate()
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='Neil Account';
        a.RecordTypeId = '012j0000000qS49';
        a.Account_Status__c = 'Active';
        Insert a;

        List<Opportunity> opp = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Integer i=0; i>2; i++)
        {
            Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
            o.AccountId = a.Id;
            o.Name = 'oppo' + i;
            o.RFP_Response_Status__c='Round 2';
            o.StageName = 'Round 1';
            o.CloseDate = date.today();
            opp.add(o);
        }
        Insert opp;


        for(Integer x=0; x>1; x++)
        {
            Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
            o.RFP_Response_Status__c = 'Out of Business';
            update opp;
        }

        opp = [select Id, Name, AccountId, RFP_Response_Status__c, StageName, CloseDate
               From Opportunity];
       system.debug('Opp' + opp); 
    }
}
```

Comment: to know if a test class is 'passing' - use the `system.assert(..)` methods to verify expected results after querying the database of the changed Opportunity(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your operators backwards in your loop. You're setting your index (i and x) to 0, then checking to see if they're *greater* than 2 or 1. This is false, and therefore the loop doesn't execute at all, so you get no coverage for your trigger. You just need to use the "less than" operator instead:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
```

And

```
for(Integer x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
```

Also note that the loop with the x index is probably not what you intended: you're calling an update on a record that doesn't have an ID value, which will cause an error. Instead, consider re-using the values in `opp`:

```
insert opp;
update opp;
```

Comment: Sorry it took me awhile to get back, I just wanted to say thank you.